# "NameError: uninitialized constant Guard::Haml::Bundler"

Tags: ruby, web-applications, haml, bundler, guard

On my OSX system, I'm trying to use Guard-Haml to auto compile my HAML down to HTML. However, when guard is running, and tries to compile, I get the error below, in fig.1. I've installed [Bunder](http://gembundler.com) and [Guard](https://github.com/guard/guard). Due to the ***NameError: uninitialized constant Guard::Haml::Bundler***, I tried, installing ***guard-bundler*** as well. But that's hasn't fixed the problem. Any insights on what needs to be done here?

Thanks 
Tim

```
...
14:33:05 - ERROR - Guard::Haml failed to achieve its <run_all>, exception was:
> [#0D0BB9E910E9] NameError: uninitialized constant Guard::Haml::Bundler
> [#0D0BB9E910E9] /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/guard-haml-0.5/lib/guard/haml.rb:44:in `run_on_changes'
> [#0D0BB9E910E9] /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/guard-haml-0.5/lib/guard/haml.rb:36:in `each'
> [#0D0BB9E910E9] /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/guard-haml-0.5/lib/guard/haml.rb:36:in `run_on_changes'
> [#0D0BB9E910E9] /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/guard-haml-0.5/lib/guard/haml.rb:32:in `run_all'
> [#0D0BB9E910E9] /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/guard-1.8.0/lib/guard/runner.rb:99:in `send'
> [#0D0BB9E910E9] /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/guard-1.8.0/lib/guard/runner.rb:99:in `run_supervised_task'
> [#0D0BB9E910E9] /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/guard-1.8.0/lib/guard/runner.rb:97:in `catch'
> [#0D0BB9E910E9] /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/guard-1.8.0/lib/guard/runner.rb:97:in `run_supervised_task'
> [#0D0BB9E910E9] /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/guard-1.8.0/lib/guard/runner.rb:54:in `run'
> [#0D0BB9E910E9] /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/guard-1.8.0/lib/guard/runner.rb:175:in `scoped_guards'
> [#0D0BB9E910E9] /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/guard-1.8.0/lib/guard/runner.rb:173:in `each'
> [#0D0BB9E910E9] /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/guard-1.8.0/lib/guard/runner.rb:173:in `scoped_guards'
> [#0D0BB9E910E9] /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/guard-1.8.0/lib/guard/runner.rb:172:in `catch'
> [#0D0BB9E910E9] /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/guard-1.8.0/lib/guard/runner.rb:172:in `scoped_guards'
> [#0D0BB9E910E9] /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/guard-1.8.0/lib/guard/runner.rb:170:in `each'
> [#0D0BB9E910E9] /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/guard-1.8.0/lib/guard/runner.rb:170:in `scoped_guards'
> [#0D0BB9E910E9] /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/guard-1.8.0/lib/guard/runner.rb:53:in `run'
> [#0D0BB9E910E9] /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/lumberjack-1.0.3/lib/lumberjack.rb:27:in `unit_of_work'
...
```

***fig.1: error output***

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

group :development do
  gem 'execjs'
  gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby
  gem 'guard-bundler'
  gem 'guard'
  gem 'guard-haml'
  gem 'guard-livereload'
  gem 'libnotify'
  gem 'rb-inotify', :require => false
  gem 'rb-fsevent', :require => false
  gem 'rb-fchange', :require => false

  gem 'compass'
  gem 'ceaser-easing'
  gem 'html5-boilerplate'
end
```

***fig.2: Gemfile***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like guard-haml [depends on Bundler](https://github.com/guard/guard-haml/blob/master/lib/guard/haml.rb#L44), but only adds [it as development dependency](https://github.com/guard/guard-haml/blob/master/guard-haml.gemspec#L18).

I did a quick test with the content in a `test.rb` file

```
::Bundler.root.to_s
```

Running it with Ruby fails

```
$ ruby test
test:1:in `<main>': uninitialized constant Bundler (NameError)
```

But running it with `bundle exec` work fine:

```
$ bundle exec test
```

So to make guard-haml work you need to run it with Bundler:

```
$ bundle exec guard
```

Comment: Hot digiddy - that works. I don't suppose there's a way to include the bundler lib? And just run guard. Anyways, this does the trick. Thanks a bunch.